# java.sql.Date set timestamp

Tags: java, hibernate

How I can set current time for java.sql.Date?

I'm using this Hibernate code for Date object:

```
@Column
@Type(type = "date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date added;
```

Comment: Don't use java.sql.Date in your entities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`java.sql.Date(long date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date-long-) constructor and `System.currentTimeMillis()`:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(sqlDate);
```

Comment: Is there any more simple way?

Comment: Implement the same solution with few lines of code.